# Not able to enter values in EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-view

I'm a newbie in Android development. Recently I have been facing a problem in the EditTexts(eventhough I havent changed any attributes of EditText) used in my app which I'm currently running in **Emulator**. 
On clicking the EditText it receives focus, but **on typing something the focus changes to some other view.** But I'm able to enter values if I navigate to EditText using Tab button of the keyboard. This happens to all EditTexts in my application.
Surfed net for getting a solution, but did not find one.Help...

Implementation of one of my EditText:

```
<EditText                   
    android:id="@+id/edittext_testname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/hintEditText1"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the activity code?

Comment: Post your activity code

Comment: I haven't started to implement logic to get data in this app. Currently activity does not have anything related to EditTexts.Anyway I'll add me main activity.

Comment: The above activity is only a portion of the code as the entire code is too big.

Answer (score 0):

Ever tried your app on a physical device?

However, I cannot see anything wrong with your EditText xml. Perhaps there is some java code in your activity catching any events related to that EditText? Or maybe to the other view element you mentioned getting the focus?

Comment: please post that as comment. It isnt realy a answer.

Comment: No I haven't implemented it on areal device.  In one particular layouts I have a collection of EditTexts, there if I enter a value in one of those EditText the focus gets shifted to some other EditText. In other layout it goes to a button.

Comment: @StefanBe you are right. Next time I will stick to your advice but unfortunately now i cannot comment and thus will let it stay this way now.
Thanks for your hint and sorry for not thinking about that in advance - still just too new here. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but with a custom style I had defined for my EditText. How I fixed it?

`<item name="android:focusable">true</item>
 <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>`

So try applying the "android:focusable" and "android:focusableInTouchMode" properties and see if it makes any difference. They should be applied to the EditText by default but give it a go.

(I would have posted this as a comment but I need more rep)